# Getting Enum value for display method x++

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, axapta, x++

I wrote a display method for an extension table. ServiceSubStatus is an enum field so 0,1,2 are displaying but I need to display the value of the enum.

Can you please help me with this?

```
    [ExtensionOf(tableStr(EntAssetObjectTable))]
public final class ObjectTable_Extension
{
    public display ServiceSubStatus ServiceSubStatus()
    {    


        return (ServiceStatus::findByRecId(this.ServiceStatus).ServiceSubStatus);

    
    }

}
```

Comment: When you put the display method on your form, what time of object did you place on the form? You can always use `enum2str()`, but what you have written _should_ work I think...

Answer (score 1):

See `enum2str()` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-conversion-run-time-functions

Check the type of object you used on the form. Sometimes an integer is used instead of a string.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the type of the control, make sure that is with enum type not integer